# URLs List / Datasource to use via .net application

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I would like to have a URLs list, simply so i could have suggestions of commonly used urls,
and bind a textbox to it as data source.

I assume every isp in the world has it, google +goolechrome +firefox can use it, how can i get hold of such common resoruce of information ?

I'll appreciate any clue at least where to start... so eventually i could make use of it with `.net` Environment.

Comment: You want a list of most commonly visited websites? This is not as trivial you think http://www.alexa.com manages this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can visit this site and try to get all the details present in Data-table where they are displaying these information.

http://www.google.com/adplanner/static/top1000

Search for this table and try to write a C# code may be wiping off the HTML before and after this table.

```
<table id="data-table">
```

I analysed this and they are displaying the entire data in this table with show/hide functionality.

So just for an idea, here are some tips:

- Read the entire HTML of this site. Store it in a text file.
- Do a substring and wipe of all the HTML before and after this   `<table>`
- Use some Regex to extract the necessary data present in this table

Comment: view source html with my I5 cpu base machine took around 30 seconds to open the file that has ~12k+ lines(:

Comment: We have worked more than these.. infact one of our app took 2 days to run and store the required data in the DB.

Comment: That was the code I wrote when I was in college.. beginner phase of C#. And the site we were crawling had some very bad directory management so we had to analyze lot of things... FYI it was just a C# console application... the client just needed the data.. he was not bothered about the way we get that data...

Comment: `html parsing` process , one of the last codes(in my latest posts) i have a solution for interaction with webclient on several websites then using `TPL` + `councurrant dictionary` and such + HtmlAgilityPack (although we could easyly use `.net` `htmlParcer()` with xpath and linq , and then, done via this aproach+ on a good multycore based rig should take ..... no time , i guess to load it up to DB will cost you around 10X no time .... so why did it take so long Sayed ? are you talking about the code "baking" the project to fine tune its code until final exe/aspx application is ready to use ?

Comment: i guess you were refering to the time took for researching the approach for **extraction of data** (which i did just these last few days) which led me to use quite a few neat methods using latest available techonlogies using .net libraries. very interesting subject (very common use on it)html parsing...

Answer (score 0):

So it seems you have about two choices:

- http://www.alexa.com => [They're managed by amazon and have an API.](http://aws.amazon.com/alexatopsites/) Cost: $0.0025 per URL returned.
- [Compete.com](https://www.compete.com/plans/) => Gives you top 200 hundred sites for + other stuff for $199/per month.

Comment: as like making money on selling air ... if i was in need say a year back i was as satisfied ...if i just didn't erase my browsers history and instesd save it to an sql database